# Silex form validation along with translation provider

Tags: validation, translation, provider, silex

I use the latest version of Silex (not the Phar-Version). I have a problem to implement the form-service provider along with the translation provider, i get the following error:

"Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\mytest\vendor\symfony\translation\Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader.php on line 47"

If I disable this line, the form shows up and everything ist fine (except the translation). I even get the message to choose from one option of the form in german language.

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());
```

Please give me a hint how to resolve this problem. Please have a look at my code and my composer.json-file below:

app.php:

```
<?php
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

use Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'locale' => 'de',
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
));
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/../views',
));

// Sample from silex-homepage
$app->match('/form', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    // some default data for when the form is displayed the first time
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'Your name',
        'email' => 'Your email',
    );

    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $data)
        ->add('name')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(1 => 'male', 2 => 'female'),
            'expanded' => true,
        ))
        ->getForm();

    if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            // do something with the data

            // redirect somewhere
            return $app->redirect('...');
        }
    }

    // display the form
    return $app['twig']->render('test.html', array('form' => $form->createView()));
});

return $app;
?>
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/config": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/filesystem": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/finder": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/form": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/locale": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/security": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.1.*",
        "monolog/monolog": ">=1.0.0,<1.2-dev",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.2.0,<2.0-dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.1.*",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Acme": "src/"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version (commit) of symfony/validator are you using? Did you try to update your vendors? The problem may have been fixed since your last update.

Comment: I used "composer.phar update" to add "symfony/config", I think this procedure updates the other vendors too? Or did I have to do something else to update them? Thanks for your help, these are my first steps with composer.

Comment: I checked the source of both the translation and the config components on github, they seem to be fine. Make sure you have the FileResource.php at its correct place in your vendor directory.

Comment: Thats it! I deleted my vendor folder and finally I got no more errors for the posted script. But I face the next problem. As soon as I add the following constraint:'code'        ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\MinLength(5))
     ))

Comment: I got a twig-error with german language: Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to choose a translation for "Diese Zeichenkette ist zu kurz. Sie sollte mindestens {{ limit }} Zeichen haben." with locale "de".") in "test.html" at line 2. I wonder, because the twig error is already translated to german language. I tried with French language an the translation is fine.